# How to define a template function of a template class outside the header?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code:

test.h

```
struct A {void funA() { cout<<"Hello"; } };

template<typename T>
struct B: public T {
  template<typename X>
  void funB(X x) {
    this->funA();
    cout<<" world, I'm " <<typeid(x).name()<<"\n";
  }
};
template class B<A>;
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
  B<A> o;      
  o.funB('a');
  o.funB(1);
}
```

Yields:

> Hello world, I'm c
>
> Hello world, I'm i

No Problem!

But I'm unable to move the definition of the function 'funB' to test.cpp.

I tried the following and failed:

test.h

```
...
  template<typename X>
  void funB(X x);
...
```

test.cpp

```
...
template<typename T>
template<typename X>
void B<T>::funB(X x) {
  this->funA();
  cout<<" world, I'm " <<typeid(x).name()<<"\n";
}
...
```

Yields:

> undefined reference to 'void B::funB(char)'
>
> undefined reference to 'void B::funB(int)'

Comment: Basically you don't.  Template code needs to live in the header file.

Comment: I don't mind explicit instantiation - As mentioned in one of the answers specified in the original(not mine) question.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  It's a lot of work for basically zero gain.

Comment: I don't mind the extra work. If it can be done I need to know how it can be done

Comment: [This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596922/explicit-instantiation-of-member-function-template-of-class-template) shows you how you would have to explicitly instantiate the templates.

Comment: As you see its a question - and at the bottom it says 'but it doesn't work'.

Comment: Look at the *I need something like: <code block> which becomes a little verbose if I start having a lot of types of T and U* part.  The last bit is the shortcut the OP tried since it can get very verbose.

Comment: Thank You...............